# Return a single value of a list of vectors in R

Tags: r, list, return-value

I am new to R and stack overflow so I am sorry if this question is unnecesary but I havent found an answer (maybe I used wrong key words).
So here is my problem.

I have a list of multiple vecors eg. :

```
x<-list(c(1:3),c(4:6),c(7:9))

> x
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 7 8 9
```

And I want to return a single value of a single vector lets say the "5"

I only managed to get the whole vector using

```
x[2]

[[1]]

[1] 4 5 6
```

but i failed to return a single value

Thanks in advance

Comment: `x[[1]]` accesses the element's contents (i.e. double-bracketing), then you can access elements of the vector as usual, e.g. `x[[1]][2]`

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the

Comment: `unlist(x)[5]` gets you there also.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the following post gives details on how to return which elements of a list: [The difference between [] and [[]] notations for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the)

To return the "5" in your specific example, you should use the following command:

```
x<-list(c(1:3),c(4:6),c(7:9))

x[[2]][2]

# > x[[2]][2]
# [1] 5
```